# Разница в поведении между let и var в цикле for

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Разница в объявлении счетчика цикла через `let` и `var` в том что через `var` переменная-счетчик видна за пределами цикла в функции, через `let` - только в пределах цикла.
Объясните пожалуйста почему в этих случаях разные выводы

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000)
```

тут получаем десять десяток.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000)
```

а тут от нуля до десяти.

С первым примером все понятно, а почему во втором так? `i` ведь создается один раз и прокручивается до начала выполнения первого `setInterval` до десятки.
Одним словом - почему в эти двух примерах разные результаты?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const

> При использовании в цикле, для каждой итерации создаётся своя переменная.
>   Переменная var – одна на все итерации цикла и видна даже после цикла.
>   С переменной let – всё по-другому.
>   Каждому повторению цикла соответствует своя независимая переменная let. Если внутри цикла есть вложенные объявления функций, то в замыкании каждой будет та переменная, которая была при соответствующей итерации.

Comment: недогуглил, спасибо )

Answer (score 6):

Все дело в области видимости переменной. Оператор let объявляет переменную которая приурочена к блочной области видимости. Что такое блочная область видимости? Вот пример

```
let a = 10;

{
   let a = 20;
   console.log(a); // 20
}

console.log(a); // 10
```

Как видно внутри блока и вне его ES6 создает совершенно разные переменные. Переменная созданная оператором let видна только в своей области видимости и вне ее области видимости к ней обратиться не возможно.

Вот что произойдет если то же самое попробовать с оператором var.

```
var a = 10;

{
   var a = 20;
   console.log(a); // 20
}

console.log(a); // 20
```

Как видишь оператор var не полностью соответствует правилам блочной видимости.

Можно твой пример можно упростить для большей ясности

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000)
```

1) Можно представить следующим образом

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(
       function(){console.log(i);}, 
          1000
    )
}
```

2) И разбить по строкам

```
{
    let i = 0;
    setTimeout(
        function(){console.log(i);},
        1000
    )
}

{
    let i = 1;
    setTimeout(
        function(){console.log(i);},
        1000
    )
}

{
    let i = 2;
    setTimeout(
        function(){console.log(i);},
        1000
    )
}
/** И так 10 раз .... 
    После 1000 миллисекунд запуститься наша тайемр-функция, и 
    поскольку в каждом блоке благодаря оператору let создавалась свая 
    переменная то в таймер-функиции будет та переменная которая была 
    создана в том же блоке.**/
```

Но с оператором var все обстоит иначе.

```
{
    var i = 0;
    setTimeout(
        function(){console.log(i);},
        1000
    )
}

{
    var i = 1;
    setTimeout(
        function(){console.log(i);},
        1000
    )
}

{
    var i = 2;
    setTimeout(
        function(){console.log(i);},
        1000
    )
}
/** И так 10 раз ...
    Поскольку во всех блоках будет одна и та же 
    переменная то после того как через 1000 миллисекунд запущенная 
    таймер-функция прочитает последнее значение переменной i - которое 
    у нас будет 10.**/
```

Как то вот так у нас обстоят дела с javascript.
Больше о блочной области видимости можешь прочитать [здесь](http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-block-scoped-declarations) и [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const).

Comment: _последнее значение переменной i - которое 
    у нас будет 9_ - если бы оно было 9 - то цикл не закончился бы

Comment: @Daniel как по вашей логике разложить тот же цикл for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
 (function(){
  var j = i;
  setTimeout( function timer(){
   console.log( j );
  }, j*1000 );
 })();
} Не могу понять как в j попадает разное значение i (пример из книги)