# При клике цвет текста не меняется

Tags: javascript

```js
var d = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for(var i = 0; i< d.length; i++){
  d[i].onclick = function(){
     // style.color = 'red';
      alert(12)
  };
};
```

```html
 <p>Параграф</p>

<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

Вот так alert выводит сообщение

```js
var d = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for(var i = 0; i< d.length; i++){
  d[i].onclick = function(){
     style.color = 'red';
      // alert(12)
  };
};
```

Вот так цвет не текста не меняется почему ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, надо указывать какому элементу применяются стили

не

> style.color = 'red';

а

> element.style.color = 'red';

или

> this.style.color = 'red';

```js
var d = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
  d[i].onclick = function() {
    d[i].style.color = 'red';

  };
};
```

```html
<p>Параграф</p>

<p>Text-1</p>
<p>Text-2</p>
<p>Text-3</p>
<p>Text-4</p>
```

А во-вторых про `let && var`

Если в цикле переменная объявлена `var i = 0 ; -- ; --`

То у нас такая картина

```js
var d = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
  d[i].onclick = function() {
    //d[i].style.color = 'red';
    console.log(i);
    this.style.color = 'red';
  };
};
```

```html
<p>Параграф</p>

<p>Text-1</p>
<p>Text-2</p>
<p>Text-3</p>
<p>Text-4</p>
```

Переменная *`i`* у нас глобальная и если раскомментировать строку

`//d[i].style.color = 'red';`

И мы получим ошибку... Так как *`i`* У нас переменная глобальная

А если в цикле переменная объявлена `let i = 0 ; -- ; --`

```js
var d = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
  d[i].onclick = function() {
    d[i].style.color = 'red';
    console.log(i);
    
  };
};
```

```html
<p>Параграф</p>

<p>Text-1</p>
<p>Text-2</p>
<p>Text-3</p>
<p>Text-4</p>
```

И мы не получим ошибку... Так как *`i`* У нас переменная локальная и видная в рамках цикла `for`

Comment: ок спасибо (какой-то текст)

Comment: почему при var выводит в консоль 5 ?

Comment: [Вот почитай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716239/Разница-в-поведении-между-let-и-var-в-цикле-for), а то одним комментом не объяснить

Comment: СПАСИБО (какой-то текст)