# Не понимаю почему выводится число 10, а не 5. JavaScript Замыкание

Tags: javascript, замыкания

```
function constfuncs() {
  let funcs = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    funcs[i] = () => i;
  }

  return funcs;
}

let funcs = constfuncs();
console.log(funcs[5]()); // => 10;
```

Нужно подробно понять механику этого процесса.

Comment: Если совсем кратко: просто замените `var i` на `let i`

Comment: @andreymal дубликатом этот пример я никак не могу назвать, но некая схожесть однозначно есть. Согласен, что можно изменить var на let, но мне хочется разобраться именно с таким вариантом.

Comment: [Разница в поведении между let и var в цикле for](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716239)

Comment: @andeymal Спасибо, ваши ссылки связанны с моим вопросом, я понимал почему должно выводиться 10, но недопонимал, почему массив тогда состоит из 10 элементов, а не только из десятого.

Comment: «почему массив тогда состоит из 10 элементов» — если кратко, потому что массив заполняется ещё в процессе работы цикла, когда `var i` ещё не успел дойти до своего окончательного значения 10. Здесь уже не имеет значения, var или let используется