# Значение функции в цикл JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, допустим есть несколько кнопок в HTML

```html
<input type="button" class="b" value="a">
<input type="button" class="b" value="b">
<input type="button" class="b" value="c">
<input type="button" class="b" value="d">
<input type="button" class="b" value="e">
```

и есть функция которая должна брать значение этих кнопок

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName ("b");
for (var i=0; i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].onclick = function show() {
        console.log(x[i].value)
}}
```

Но x[i] который в console.log находится вне цикла и принимает конечное значение i после завершение цикла, так вот вопрос в том, как ввести этот i внутрь цикла, чтобы значение функции соответствовало значению кнопки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
for (var i=0; ...
```

писать

```
for (let i=0; ...
```

Comment: Ого, и правда работает, а можете объяснить почему ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716239/191482  тут два ответа

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей

Comment: Если ответ правильный, поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку.

Answer (score 0):

## Ответ

События в цикле имеют побочный эффект. При вызове события `i` уже ровно `x.length` и не важно, что цикл завершился. Решаем этот момент таким образом:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("b");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let iCopy = i;
    x[iCopy].onclick = function show() {
        console.log(x[iCopy].value);
    };
}
```